# implicit method for method

Tags: function, scala, methods, implicit

I am trying to add implicit method for functions of concrete type.

```
implicit class ComposeMethods(one: (=>Unit) => Unit) {
  def &(another: => Unit) {
    one(another)
  }
}

def method(u: => Unit) {u}

method _ & {println(1000)} // works perfectly 
method & {println(1000)} // doesn't work
```

For functions it works, but I want to apply `&` for my methods and without making them functions explicitly (`_`). Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot see the difference between the two last lines :(

Comment: @Ashalynd, thanks! This was a typo, fixed.

Comment: I don't think thats possible without explicitly converting a method to a function. Methods are not first class.